# Still "Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'."

Tags: angular

I've spent two days on all possible solutions found (see below), and upgraded both Angular and Material from 7 to 8, still the same complaint.

> can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'

1. `import` and `@NgModule` in both app.module.ts and component.ts
   (tried partial as well, all possible combination`)
2. swap out `<table` for `<mat-table`
3. `[dataSource]` not `[datasource]`

app.module.ts

```
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';  // or just @angular/material
@NgModule({
  imports:
  [
    MatTableModule // adding MatTableDataSource here will get Error at component.ts: Unexpected value 'MatTableDataSource' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation
  ]})
```

component.ts

```
import {MatTableModule, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
@NgModule({
    imports: [MatTableModule, MatTableDataSource]
  })
```

component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="myArray">
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row"></tr>
</table>
```

package.json, tried v8.0.1 for material as well:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Tried all these:
[Angular7 - Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185437/angular7-cant-bind-to-datasource-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-mat-ta)

[ERROR: Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-tree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027376/error-cant-bind-to-datasource-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-mat-tree)

[Material Design Table is not accepting dataSource object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177086/material-design-table-is-not-accepting-datasource-object)

[mat-table can't bind dataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298241/mat-table-cant-bind-datasource)

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11906

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T730641/the-can-t-bind-to-datasource-since-it-isn-t-a-known-property-of-dx-data-grid-error-occurs

https://www.oipapio.com/question-941474

https://code-examples.net/en/q/2fe6baa

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: **can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'** complained by Angular runtime.

Comment: You could try my table component https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez/ and a demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npn1p1. Much easier to use than a mat-table

Comment: Excellent research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a while to figure it out, the "component" is in a "module" as this structure **`app\module\component`**, so regardless everything was right in `app.module.ts` they are not in the right container. After adding the necessary `import` and `@NgModule({ imports: [] })` into **`module.ts`**, works!